# Error while installing Android Studio in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04

I encountered the following error while attempting to install Android Studio in Ubuntu. How do I solve this issue? I am using jdk 1.8
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For UBUNTU 16.04 LTS just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

then restart Android Studio it will work.